# Laravel. cant get value from nested collection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing push command in controller adding to collection.
this is inside a while loop, after receiving data from $send1

```
$send3->push($send1);
```

$send3 and $send1 are both collections

After the while loop I'm echoing $send3 and it gives me

```
[{"id":31,"info":3},[{"id":0,"info":1}]]
```

I would like to get info from both(or many), in example : 3,1

How can I do to either make it this way :

```
[{"id":31,"info":3},{"id":0,"info":1}]
```

or get info values from the nested collection?

Comment: You should use clean format to be able to use methods like `pluck()` or `array_pluck`. Now it will not work and you'll need to manually iterate over the collection and get the data. So, you should fix the code which you're using to build the collection and add data to the collection. Please show the code.

Answer (score 4):

You've said that `$send3` and `$send1` are both collections. In this case, use the `merge()` method to add the data instead of the `push()`:

```
$send3 = $send3->merge($send1);
```

Then you'll be able to use `pluck()`:

```
$send3->pluck('info')
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the collections and then use the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$merged = $send1->merge($send3);
$plucked = $merged->pluck('info')->toArray();

// [3, 1]
```

Comment: i tried using pluck, but it just gives me this as result :  [{"id":31,"info":3}] . and i need all the results, not just the first

Comment: Chain toArray() off it.

Comment: which one should i array? also what is inside the pluck is another collection

Comment: You need to merge the collections together first

Comment: alright guys, i tried to do as spoken, but it just gives me 1 as result.

Comment: the merge is just getting 1 data

Comment: issue fixed. made an array of both and plucked both